# Connect Google Cloud Run with Google Compute Engine or GKE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-run

Is there a way to connect Google Cloud Run with a service running in a Compute Engine instance in an specific port?

With Google Cloud Run I want to run a WebApp that needs to connect with a service running in Compute Engine or Google Kubernetes Engine. It's that possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, this is possible. You need to create a [VPC Serverless connector](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/connecting-vpc) and use it to connect to the internal IPs of the VMs in GCE or any resource in the VPC.

Comment: I'm trying to run a WebApp on GCR and connect to a Hyperledger Fabric network running on GCE or GKE, but I'm having connection errors. I set firewall rules and I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: If you've already created the connector, then create a new question and show what you've done and the errors you get